# Firebug: open console during debugging in script tab

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, console, firebug

When I'm debugging javascript in Firebug I have to switch frequently between the console and the script tab, whereas in Webkit Inspector I can just open a console from the bottom.

I think it's easier to inspect variables and object using the console (or to test methods), instead of the graphical tools.

Is there a way to have both the console and the debugging window opened at the same time in firebug, like in Chrome or Safari?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. In the script tab, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and the console (*Command Line Popup*, as the [doc says](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts)) will appear at the bottom (as in Chrome).

To turn it off, press <kbd>ESC</kbd>.